# What happens if the block's generated are exactly 10 minutes?

Tags: bitcoin-core, block, block-interval

My understanding is that every 2016 blocks, the average block time is taken. If it is less than 10 minutes, network ramps up the difficulty. Is there a possibility where the average block time is exactly 10 minutes. What happens in such case?

Answer (score 4):

Exactly nothing. The difficulty would remain the same.